# OnlineOAuth2TokenValidator + Spring Security + Spring WebFlux + WebClient

Tags: spring-security, jwt, spring-webflux

I am currently developing an application using Spring Webflux and Spring Security (Spring Boot 3.1.4) to ensure security. To achieve this, I am utilizing the Spring Boot Starter OAuth2 Resource Server dependency. During the validation process of the JWT token, I require an HTTP query validation to the identity provider (IDP). I have created a `NimbusReactiveJwtDecoder` and now intend to set up my custom validator. This necessitates the implementation of the `OAuth2TokenValidator<Jwt>` interface.

Considering the use of a reactive stack, I am employing WebClient. However, the validate method from `OAuth2TokenValidator<Jwt>` returns `OAuth2TokenValidatorResult` instead of `Mono<OAuth2TokenValidatorResult>`. This makes it challenging to directly return the result of `webclient.get().uri().retrieve()`. Additionally, within the reactive context, methods like `block()`, `blockOptional()`, `blockFirst()` and `blockLast()` cannot be used.

My implementation looks like that:

```java
@Override
public OAuth2TokenValidatorResult validate(Jwt token) {
    return this.webClient
        .get()
        .uri(tokenValidationUri, token.getTokenValue())
        .retrieve()
        .toBodilessEntity()
        .map(ResponseEntity::getStatusCode)
        .map(statusCode -> {
            if (statusCode.is2xxSuccessful()) {
                return success();
            }
            return failure(createOAuth2Error());
        }).onErrorResume(throwable -> Mono.just(failure(createOAuth2Error())));
}
```

Dependencies:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

My problem is that I don't know how to properly code such a validator. Or maybe there other approaches?

Comment: Looks like what you are looking for is access token introspection (instead of JWT decoding). In Spring Security, this configuration is done with `resourceServer(rs -> rs.opaqueToken(server -> {}))` DSL (instead of `resourceServer(rs -> rs.jwt(server -> {}))`, and yes, you can process a JWT as an opaque string if your authorization server exposes an introspection endpoint)

Comment: `During the validation process of the JWT token, I require an HTTP query validation to the identity provider (IDP)` what do you mean by this sentance, what is it you need to validate? please provide more details